# Configure rsnapshot to keep initial(first) backup forever?

Tags: server, backup, rsync, rsnapshot

How could I tell rsnapshot to keep the initial (ie., the very first backup) backup of my server forever, incase I may need it in some rare time (like for some files in /etc directory ) ?

Answer (score 0):

There is a utility called rsnaptar which can be found in the utils folder located in /usr/share/doc/rsnapshot-*/ area depending on your rsnpashot installation. From the rsnaptar file itself is a brief description:

> A quick hack of a shell script to tar up backup points from the
>   rsnapshot snapshot root. Sends an e-mail to an address specified on
>   the command line when finished.

So you can use this script utility to tar up your initial backup and keep it handy.